# Github API Add user to private repository

Tags: php, api, github

If im not mistaken the github API documentation says that this is the correct way to do so:

https://api.github.com/repos/REPOOWNER/REPONAME/collaborators/USERTOINVITE?permission=pull&access_token=OWNERTOKEN

However I get the response of 'Not Found' whenever doing this. If anyone knows how to do this please let me know.

Comment: Your colleague is a member at github?

Comment: Yes, there account exists.